# boost::factory creating boost::enable_shared_from_this class

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr, boost-function

I have multiple class derivated from A

```
class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<A>    pointer;

        static pointer create(tcp::socket& socket) {
            return pointer(new A(socket));
        }
    private:
        A(&tcp::socket socket) : m_socket(socket) {}

        tcp::socket&    m_socket;
}

Class Aa : public A {
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<Aa>   pointer;

        static pointer create(tcp::socket& socket) {
            return pointer(new Aa(socket));
        }

    private:
        Aa(&tcp::socket socket) : A(socket) {}
}

Class Ab : public A {
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<Ab>   pointer;

        static pointer create(tcp::socket& socket) {
            return pointer(new Ab(socket));
        }

    private:
        Ab(&tcp::socket socket) : A(socket) {}
}
```

[...]

```
Class Ax : public A {
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<Ax>   pointer;

        static pointer create(tcp::socket& socket) {
            return pointer(new Ax(socket));
        }

    private:
        Ax(&tcp::socket socket) : A(socket) {}
}
```

I would like to create a factory pattern using boost::factory
I have writted something like that :

```
class MyFactory {
    public:
        static MyFactory* getInstance();

        typedef boost::function< A(tcp::socket) > a_fact;

    private:
        MyFactory() {
            map["Aa"] = boost::bind(boost::factory< Aa::create >, _1);
            map["Ab"] = boost::bind(boost::factory< Ab::create >, _1);
            […]
            map["Ax"] = boost::bind(boost::factory< Ax::create >, _1);
        }

        std::map<std::string, a_fact>   map;
    };
```

And of course, it does not compil...
giving me the error :

```
MyFactory.cc:13: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Pointer, class Allocator, boost::factory_alloc_propagation AP> class boost::factory’
MyFactory.cc:13: error:   expected a type, got ‘Aa::create’
```

Any idea, how should I implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone goes into the same mistake, Here the answer.
It does not need `boost::factory` to work, using `boost::function` directly is enough.

so

```
class MyFactory {
    public:
        static MyFactory* getInstance();

        typedef boost::function< A(tcp::socket) > a_fact;

    private:
        MyFactory() {
            map["Aa"] = boost::bind(&Aa::create, _1);
            map["Ab"] = boost::bind(&Ab::create, _1);
            […]
            map["Ax"] = boost::bind(&Ax::create, _1);
        }

        std::map<std::string, a_fact>   map;
    };
```

**Works great !!!**

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/index.html) the argument passed to the `factory`-template is the pointer type you expect as a result. So in your case `boost::factory<Aa::pointer>`.

Comment: This won't work since I should call static create method, instead of the Constructor...